# Flag alert for no flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flags

On Android and Meta-Android I'm seeing the flags alert in the header with a count of zero.

[image: screen shot]

While the display of that alert in the past has occasionally been hit-or-miss, I don't think it should be displaying when there are no flags to handle.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on both too, with nothing showing in the queue for either. Could these possibly be Mod-only flags?

Comment: It looks like it might be a network-wide thing. I'm showing a "1" on Web Apps, but I handled that flag.

Comment: There are no mod flags at the moment, so it does appear to be a bug. Possibly worth noting as well is that I do *not* see the "0", so perhaps it's just the 10k flag counter that's misbehaving.

Comment: Appears to be a network-wide issue: [Posts flagged for attention but there are none](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189856)

Comment: This [should be fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189872/21960). I think this can be [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: Too Localized needs to be re-added for Meta.